# How to set background image with two alternative image? (set substitute image when there is no image)

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'd like to set background-image.
There are two alternative image.
Here is my code.

```
<a id="test" style="bakckground: url('image1.png'), bakckground: url('image2.png');">test</a>
```

I want to check first image(image1.png) and if there is no image, I'd like to set second image(image2.png). And If there is first image, then set first image(image1.png).

If I put above code, when there are both image that exists, then It sets both image on a tag...

I want to check first image, and if it is exists, I want to set only first image.
And If there is second image, set only second image.

Please give me an advice for solve this..

If there is no answer for that, Is there any chance for catch on jQuery event?
I tried to catch error with below code, but couldn't catch an error..

```
$("[id='test']").error(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .error() called." )
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`background` Able to set multiple backgrounds.

```
background:url("bg1.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat,
           url("bg2.jpg") 200px 0 no-repeat
```

The `bg1` layer is above `bg2`, If `bg1` does not exist, it is hidden. `bg2` is shown automatically。

Try changing the image links you can use

```css
.bg-wrap {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  /* Try deleting the bg1 background url */
    background: url("https://dss2.bdstatic.com/70cFvnSh_Q1YnxGkpoWK1HF6hhy/it/u=248222817,375547763&fm=26&gp=0.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat,
                url("https://dss2.bdstatic.com/70cFvnSh_Q1YnxGkpoWK1HF6hhy/it/u=2901784552,1261367458&fm=26&gp=0.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-wrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a add pseudo element "before" and set the dimension similar to its parent. Please see my code below. I don't know if this is what you want but hope this can help you.

```css
#test {
  color: green;
  background: url(https://dummyimagee.com/100x100/000/fff); /* wrong path */
  /* background: url(https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff); */ /* correct path */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#test::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ff0000/0011ff);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a id="test">test</a>
```